# Hide and move divs depending on device in Bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am using Bootstrap to create a layout that displays for desktop, tablet and mobile. What I am trying to achieve is illustrated here:

[image]

To do this I have created three divs:

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-3">Text</div>
  <div class="col-md-3">Text</div>
  <div class="col-md-3">Text</div>
</div>
```

The middle div will be hidden on tablet view, then the last div will fall below the first on mobile view.

Using what I currently have, all three divs display correctly on desktop, but in tablet & mobile all three collapse vertically.

Is there an easy way to do this with Bootstrap, or must I write my own CSS media queries?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To hide the middle div, use utilities class described in bootstrap:

### Bootstrap 3

[**Bootstrap doc**](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#responsive-utilities)

[image]

Use the `visible-lg` class to hide the div on tablets and phones.

I suggest to use col-sm and col-xs to collapse or not the div depending the width ([**Learn more about grid system**](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid)):

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-sm-3 col-xs-9">Text</div>
  <div class="col-sm-3 visible-lg">Text</div>
  <div class="col-sm-3 col-xs-9">Text</div>
</div>
```

See this [**fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/7Ldm3/1/)

---

### Bootstrap 2.3

[**Bootstrap doc**](http://getbootstrap.com/2.3.2/scaffolding.html#responsive)

[image]

Use the `visible-desktop` class to hide the div on tablets and phones.

Comment: Thanks for the effort you put into this answer, it is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

```
.row {width:100%;position:relative;}
.col-md-3{width:3.33333%;float:left;padding:10px;height:100px;}
```

Answer (score 1):

Apart from @Getz answer here are some references addressing your issues in detail.

- [Media Queries: How to target desktop, tablet and mobile?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6370690/media-queries-how-to-target-desktop-tablet-and-mobile)
- [Media Queries for standard devices](http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/media-queries-for-standard-devices/)

To target a device then just write `min-device-width`. For example:

For iPhone

```
@media only screen and (min-device-width: 480px){
.middle_div { display: none;}
/* other responsive styles*/
}
```

For tablets

```
@media only screen and (min-device-width: 768px){
.middle_div { display: none;}
}
```

A best possible solution to workout for all devices

```
/* Smartphones (portrait and landscape) ----------- */
@media only screen 
and (min-device-width : 320px) 
and (max-device-width : 480px) {
/* Styles */
}

/* Smartphones (landscape) ----------- */
@media only screen 
and (min-width : 321px) {
/* Styles */
}

/* Smartphones (portrait) ----------- */
@media only screen 
and (max-width : 320px) {
/* Styles */
}

/* iPads (portrait and landscape) ----------- */
@media only screen 
and (min-device-width : 768px) 
and (max-device-width : 1024px) {
/* Styles */
}

/* iPads (landscape) ----------- */
@media only screen 
and (min-device-width : 768px) 
and (max-device-width : 1024px) 
and (orientation : landscape) {
/* Styles */
}

/* iPads (portrait) ----------- */
@media only screen 
and (min-device-width : 768px) 
and (max-device-width : 1024px) 
and (orientation : portrait) {
/* Styles */
}

/* Desktops and laptops ----------- */
@media only screen 
and (min-width : 1224px) {
/* Styles */
}

/* Large screens ----------- */
@media only screen 
and (min-width : 1824px) {
/* Styles */
}

/* iPhone 4 ----------- */
@media
only screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio : 1.5),
only screen and (min-device-pixel-ratio : 1.5) {
/* Styles */
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<div class="row visible-lg">
  <div class="col-md-4">Text</div>
  <div class="col-md-4">Text</div>
  <div class="col-md-4">Text</div>
</div>

<div class="row visible-md">
  <div class="col-md-6">Text</div>
  <div class="col-md-6">Text</div>
 </div>
<div class="row visible-sm">
  <div class="col-md-12">Text</div>      
 </div>
<div class="row visible-sm">
  <div class="col-md-12">Text</div>      
 </div>
```

Comment: That could be a solution for bootstrap 2.3, but with the new grid system in v3, it can be done more simply.

Comment: @Getz yes i saw your answer ..not a bootsrap guy...i use foundation..:)